Redis cloud data usage limit
I'm currently using redis for my personal project and I'm kinda new to it, so firstly I created an account to use the free redis cloud with aws as my cloud provider and it gives me a total of 30MB space.
I've already used up 2mb of space for testing some operation and which is using nodejs "bull.js" library to create a job queue and storing the operation/job to be executed asynchronously.
I would like to know from someone who is quite experienced with redis cloud whether the alloted space will free up as the job is done or will it remain persistent?
I tried browsing the web for answers but couldn't get a solid answer
